# Convert ISO8601 String to NSDate with correct timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsdate

The server sends the following time to my iOS app via JSON when I get Blog Posts from a server

```
"createdAt": "2013-05-11 05:54:07.589698"
```

However, when, it is outputted to the screen in PostsViewController, it says 5:54 AM (4 hours ahead of local time)

But when I create a post, PostsViewController, will say a time like 1:54 AM (correct)

So I went investigating, and I checked the SQLite, and converted from time seconds past some date in 2001 format to GMT mode. And the posts from the server are actually 4 hours ahead of what they should be.

*Basically, not all the NSDate's are being set to GMT in Core Data, the posts that come from the server are set to GMT+4 for some reason.*

Note, that currently, I am 4 hours behind GMT.

All my server times are all ok in one timeformat (GMT)

I use Peter Hosey's ISO8601DateFormatter currently https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter:

```
post.createdDate = [formatter dateFromString:[post_info objectForKey:@"createdAt"]];
```

**So how, do I stop this double offsetting of the time difference?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, since I was using a custom date formatter, these suggestions put me on the right track (and the ideas were right), but the implementation for this library is slightly different.

**I just added a 'Z' at the end of the string, and that worked. Z indicates that it is in UTC timezone.**

I just thought I'd add this answer, in case, anyone else has this same problem, and is using the ISO8601DateFormatter library.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your time is GMT you just need to set the timeZone to the dateFormatter

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-05-11 05:54:07.589698";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

//Time zone changed to your local  
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
//Set a new dateFormat if you want 

NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the date formatted what time zone it should be using, otherwise it will use the time zone of the device.